# Using RSACryptoServiceProvider on AzureFunction

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm moving an existing DLL to Azure function to generate and sign a Hash.

Although when I'm using rsaPrivate.FromXmlString(privKey); the azure function retrieves error 500. Without it I am able to retrieve the hash. It seems that on azure I cannot define a RSACryptoServiceProvider type somehow.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

```
    string sHash = String.Empty;
    string privKey = "MyXMLkey";
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaPrivate = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    try
    {
        //rsaPrivate.FromXmlString(privKey); //Troubled line

        SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
        byte[] rawSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name);
        byte[] signedSecretData = rsaPrivate.SignData(rawSecret, SHA1.Create());
        sHash = Convert.ToBase64String(signedSecretData);
    }
    catch
    {
        sHash="Couldnt sign or generate hash";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify that the key be created in a machine store while initializing RSACryptoServiceProvider class.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters csp = new CspParameters();
csp.KeyContainerName = "MyKeyName";
csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;

System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I've tried the code you specified but It's still not running. 
With this code, I still need to sign with RsaPrivate.FromXmlString(privkey) right?
If I'm using UseMachineKeyStore, am I still able to use my xml privKey declared on code?