# Azure function RSA decrypt code not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, rsa, .net-core-3.1, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to decrypt a sting in azure function using private key . The code is working fine on my local PC but when i try to execute the code via azure function deployed it is throwing error 500 .
I am new to azure hence seeking some good advice . After disabling few method inside the code i found out the method that is actually breaking the code. Below is the code part when commented function is giving 200 response but not the actual output because this code is decrypting the key .

```
        using (var rsa = RSAWrapper.Create())
        {
            rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privkey), out _); // passing the private key here 
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            byte[] bytesEncrypted = rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
            output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: internal server error 500 is what i can identify only

Comment: You should be apple to see the exception using log streaming. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/streaming-logs

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified in the error . I am currently passing private key hardcoded in a string in azure function . on local is is working but not via aure function . Are there any security settings at azure function to consume private key ?

Comment: have you gone through this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55371115) where we have a related discussion? about 500 internal errors with RSA Crypto service provider

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the below steps if that helps to:**

> I am currently passing private key hardcoded in a string in azure function . on local is is working but not via Azure function . Are there any security settings at azure function to consume private key ?

**AFAIK, you can secure the RSA Private Keys using Azure Key Vault instead of hardcoding in the Azure Functions Project.**

***As we know that Azure Key Vault is the place where we can store/import/maintain the keys and secrets essential for our cloud applications and where we do not have direct access to it.***

**Here is an article you can find the practical workaround that [retrieves Azure Key Vault Secrets using Azure Functions and Managed Service Identity](https://integration.team/blog/retrieve-azure-key-vault-secrets-using-azure-functions-and-managed-service-identity/).**

**Here are the few references that helps you the issues recorded on storing the RSA private keys/certificates on Azure key vault along with their resolution discussions:**

1. [Is it possible to put RSA Private Keys in Azure Key Vault Certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669596/is-it-possible-to-put-rsa-private-keys-in-azure-key-vault-certificates)
2. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50164